# How to send input to window opened by Python3 subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, user-input, dosbox

I'm using Python3 to run an MS-DOS simulator (`dosbox`). The idea is to set this up in a Raspberry Pi and have my own arcade machine, but  I'll use python to make a decent looking GUI to be able to choose which game to play and have it launch automatically.

However, `dosbox` launches the program in a new window, and I need to control input and output to that window. This is to standardize key-bindings (have all games using the same key-set) and to set some automatic key-presses for certain games to start automatically.

```
import os
import pygame
import subprocess
import time

cwd = os.getcwd()
cmd = ['dosbox', cwd+'/Hi-Octane/HiOctane/EXECUTOR.EXE']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(2)
out, err = p.communicate('1'.encode('utf-8'))
print(out)
```

In the code above, I try to send a '1' (as in, someone pressed the `1` key) to the window (it's what the game needs to have pressed to start running).

TL;DR: **How do I simulate keypresses or mousepresses and send input into a window opened by a subprocess in calling?**

Comment: You need the `keyboard` library in combination with something that will focus the window, such as pywin32 (for windows).

Comment: @xaav the point is to run the EXE of windows but it needs input of keyboard to end it's process, and it will remain stuck over there unless a keyboard input given physically. Right now i am facing similar issue as subprocess.run('some_exe') is running and asking "Press Any Key To Exit" while i have already mentioned "keyboard.press_and_release('enter')" and it's coming to next line unless we press the button